# Image titles not displaying in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I wish to display images in a loop with the image name as a title. Each image displays in the loop but the title does not.

In the function below, the `img_list` contains lists with the following `[image, image_title]`.

```
def display_images(img_list, cmap='gray', cols = 2, fig_size = (10, 10) ):
    """
    Display images in img_list
    """
    i = 1  # for subplot
    
    num_images = len(img_list)
    num_rows = num_images / cols
    
    plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)       
       
    for image in img_list:
        image_file_name = image[1]
        plt.subplot(num_rows, cols, i)        
        plt.title = image_file_name
        plt.imshow(image[0], cmap=cmap)        
        i += 1     

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you reassign `plt.title`, the `title()` function is overwritten by a string.

Instead you need to **call** the `plt.title()` function.

```
plt.title(image_file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked. And for others who find this answer, the kernel needs to be restarted after making the change. Otherwise you will get a ''str' object is not callable'" error.